# Why does md5sum give inconsistent results on device files?

Tags: devices, dd, usb-drive, hashsum

Backing up some USB flash-drives on Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Plug USB drive into laptop. Automounter does its stuff. I remount all partitions as read-only

`sudo mount -o remount,ro /dev/sdxn`

Copy USB drive to image file on hard disk using ddrescue (restartable)

`sudo ddrescue -b 4096 /dev/sdx sdx.img sdx.log`

(Note: blocksize determined by `sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/sdx` )

`md5sum sdx.img` gives result < foo >

*purge* disk buffers: 
    `sudo blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sdx`

- otherwise subsequent command reads disk cache and not the actual disk (as confirmed by looking at the activity light on the USB drive, and the speed of completion of later commands).

`sudo md5sum /dev/sdx` gives result < bar >

So it seems the copy failed.

BUT

a *subsequent* `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc bs=4096 | md5sum`

gives result < foo > again !!! WHAT?

It turns out dd (and ddrescue) generates consistent images, all with the same md5sum, but if I md5sum the device file directly, I get different md5sum results.

Have I missed something obvious? Most howtos advise using md5sum on the device file, so I guess I have either found a bug/feature, or been idiotic and missed something blindingly obvious. Any clues?

(Note, I'm generating images of the USB drives, as some of them are bootable, with a useful set of tools on them. This takes up space, so for the larger drives, I will reduce the storage requirement by using mksquashfs ( `mksquashfs sdx.img sdx.squash.img` ). This works well, so long as I change the ownership of the image file from root to my username before mksquashfs. This means I get mountable compressed images, so browsing the contents is easy. There's probably a better way.

[Edit to add: having seen [hdd-image-file-checksum-does-not-match-with-device-checksum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232974/hdd-image-file-checksum-does-not-match-with-device-checksum?rq=1) I can say that `sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdx` and the size of the image file on disk are precisely the same.]

[Further update:

`$ sudo cat /dev/sdx | md5sum
a4db504f408c139cd2517b4038dfdb2f  -
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdx | md5sum
2038272+0 records in
2038272+0 records out
1043595264 bytes (1.0 GB, 995 MiB) copied, 105.895 s, 9.9 MB/s
e6174ed97f010cc7aa2ea9669cd85c50  -
$ sudo md5sum /dev/sdx
823b619d439fbb0abde5841097c76e72  /dev/sdx`

Then repeat

`$ sudo cat /dev/sdx | md5sum
a4db504f408c139cd2517b4038dfdb2f  -
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdx | md5sum
2038272+0 records in
2038272+0 records out
1043595264 bytes (1.0 GB, 995 MiB) copied, 105.747 s, 9.9 MB/s
e6174ed97f010cc7aa2ea9669cd85c50  -
$ sudo md5sum /dev/sdx
823b619d439fbb0abde5841097c76e72  /dev/sdx`

So the behavior is repeatable - using cat, dd, and direct md5sum gives different answers, but apparently cat gives the same answer each time as does dd, and as does md5sum.

Since I can use `cat`, `dd`, `ddrescue`, or `pv` to copy the contents of the device to an on-disk image, which is 'correct'?]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/calculate-md5sum-of-a-cd-dvd it seems that in the case you do a md5sum on the block device itself, it takes into account blank space

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET But cat and dd should also read the blank space.