# md5sum of partition and img do not match

Tags: linux, dd

I booted Ubuntu on a live USB and ran:

dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mnt/usb/backup.img bs=30M oflag=sync

I then performed a comparison (using 'md5sum') of the above input partition and output img, but they did not match. Delving further, I found the img was shorter by 1 byte hence the mismatch! 'cmp' of the two returns "EOF on image".

[HDD image file checksum does not match with device checksum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232974/hdd-image-file-checksum-does-not-match-with-device-checksum) mentions that dd stopped at EOF and this is normal behaviour, but I am still unclear on the entire situation...

My questions are:

1- What does EOF means in the context of a partition? I think I understand EOF in the context of a file but this is different as I would expect to find EOF at the end of the partition only.
2- Is restoring the dd img (dd if=/mnt/usb/backup.img if=/dev/sda1) safe?
3- What is in that last byte?

Thanks

Comment: shorter by 1 byte? how did you determine that? commands and outputs? - linked question is about the other direction, not your issue.

Comment: "blockdev --getsize64 /mnt/usb/backup.img" reported one less byte than "blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda1"

Comment: The linked question seems very different. In that case the partition contains stuff beyond the end of the image. But in your case if you did partition → image, then I would expect them to match.